# nginx in front of apache doesn't load images

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

i configured a nginx will run on 80, and Apache 8081 
here is my virtualhost config:

```
server {
    listen 123.123.123.123:80;
    server_name edm1.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/edm1.mydomain.com_nginx_access_log;
    error_log  /var/log/virtualmin/edm1.mydomain.com_nginx_error_log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://123.123.123.123:8081;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpe?g|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mp3)$ {
        expires 30d;
        root /home/edm1/public_html
    }
}
```

when i access the page, the images will not load (if i remove the line location..., the images will be loaded), and the page is keeping loading (a rotating icon in title bar), when i open /var/log/virtualmin/edm1.mydomain.com_nginx_error_log, it says "permission denied", how can i fix the problem?

Comment: You are missing a `;` in your `root` statement, and you should generally use `alias` instead of `root` inside `location` blocks.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have enough permission on /home/edm1/

try to chmod to 744

Comment: Why not make the nginx instance run as the user that owns the website?